# How to redirect to another page after Stripe React successful response?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a very simple React app that uses Stripe to process payments. Payment processing works and I am receiving successful response. However, I cannot figure out how to redirect to another page. I am using react-router-dom.
Here is what I have:

Index.js (starting point):

```
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
```

App.js (Route definition to Payment.js and onSuccessfulResponse handler):

```
handleCheckout( status) {
    // HOWTO: redirect to success page?
    if (status === "success") {
       // history.push("/pymt/success");   // fails with  Unexpected use of 'history'
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/pymt/success">
                    <PymtSuccess />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/pymt">
                    <Payment onSuccessfulResponse={(status) => this.handleCheckout( status) } />
                </Route>
```

Payment.js contains only UI elements to display Stripe payment form:

```
                <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
                    <CheckoutForm onSuccessfulResponse={( status) => this.props.onSuccessfulResponse( status) } />
                </Elements>
```

CheckoutForm.js processes payment. I am triggering onSuccessfulResponse with this code:

```
if (succeeded) {
    //return <div>Charge suceeded!</div>
    onSuccessfulResponse("success");
}
```

It goes to App.js -> handleCheckout function. But I cannot get it to go to another page.

I've been trying to solve this for the whole day with no luck. Greatly appreciate your effort in helping solve this!

Thank you!

Comment: Is `App.js` being rendered into a `Router` component? How is `history` being created/passed to `App.js`? Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example for `App` and how it is rendered into your `Router`?

Answer (score 1):

History is not being passed to App.js.
I have solved it by using {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom':

App.js:

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
class App extends Component{
...
handleCheckout(status){
   const {history} = this.props;
   if (status){
        history.push("/pymt/success");
   }
}

....
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

Route props are not being passed to `App` component, so `history` is undefined.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```

## Solution

Wrap `App` component with the [withRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) Higher Order Component to have the [route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) injected.

```
import { ..., withRouter, ... } from 'react-router-dom';

...

export default withRouter(App);
```

Now `this.props.history` will be defined and usable.

```
handleCheckout( status) {
  if (status === "success") {
    this.props.history.push("/pymt/success");
  }
}
```

## Solution 2

Convert `App` to a functional component and use the [useHistory](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) React hook from `react-router-dom`.

`App`

```
import { ..., useHistory, ... } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const history = useHistory();

...

handleCheckout( status) {
  if (status === "success") {
    history.push("/pymt/success");
  }
}
```